# Network Graph output from Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm pretty new to using Scrapy and I'm having difficulties.  I'm trying to work with scrapy to crawl a website and return a list of nodes and edges to build a network graph of internal and external websites from my start page to a depth of x (to be determined).

I have the following code and I'm having trouble figuring out what the issue is.

My items.py file looks like this:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class SitegraphItem(Item):
     url=Field()
     linkedurls=Field()
```

my graphspider.py file is as follows:

```
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.utils.url import urljoin_rfc
from sitegraph.items import SitegraphItem

class GraphspiderSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'graphspider'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.example.com/products/']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'/'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        i = SitegraphItem()
        i['url'] = response.url
        i['http_status'] = response.status
        llinks=[]
        for anchor in hxs.select('//a[@href]'):
            href=anchor.select('@href').extract()[0]
            if not href.lower().startswith("javascript"):
                llinks.append(urljoin_rfc(response.url,href))
        i['linkedurls'] = llinks
        return i
```

and I modified the settings.py file to include:

```
BOT_NAME = 'sitegraph'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['sitegraph.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'sitegraph.spiders'
FEED_FORMAT="jsonlines"
FEED_URI="C:\\Users\Merrie\\Desktop\\testscrape\\sitegraph\\sitegraph.json"
```

When I run it I'm using the following code:

$ scrapy crawl graphspider -o attempt2.csv

And my output table is empty.  It also keeps throwing this error: "KeyError: 'SitegraphItem does not support field: http_status'"

Answer (score 1):

Missing `http_status`field  in your items.py causes the error, please update it.

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class SitegraphItem(Item):
    url=Field()
    linkedurls=Field()
    http_status=Field()
```